# Adding urls api keys in environment variable in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a url that I am using in one of the controllers. Is there a better place to put this url? The url uses an API key and I was wondering if there is a better place to add this url and/or api key such that its not added in the controller class code and ergo more editable? If i add it as an environment variable or anything else how do i access it from my controller class? thank you. ITS A RUBY AND RAILS PROJECT

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I store keys for API's in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295889/how-do-i-store-keys-for-apis-in-rails)

Answer (score 6):

Using environment variables might be a good idea if you want to keep things like API keys and passwords out of your source code. Accessing them from within your code is done with the `ENV` object:

```
my_api_key = ENV['MY_API_KEY']
```

To use this technique, you need to set up the variables in your environment before launching your app, and how you do this depends on your local setup, and will likely also vary between development and production.

In development, you can simply set the environment vars in your shell, e.g. with bash:

```
$ export MY_API_KEY=foobar123abc
$ rails s
```

Now rails will start and have access to this environment variable. You can also set variables for just a single command:

```
$ MY_API_KEY=foobar123abc rails s
```

Depending on what the sevice/api is, you could set some of them to default development/test values in `config/environments/development.rb` (or `test.rb`):

```
ENV['MY_API_KEY'] = 'non_secret_api_key_that_can_be_shared_around'
```

Setting up environment variables in production will depend on how you're deploying your app. Phusion have an [article on using environment variables in Passenger](http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/12/16/passing-environment-variables-to-ruby-from-phusion-passenger/) if your using that. There's also a useful [article on using environment variables with Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which is worth a read even if you're not using them for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to application.rb file as

```
config.service {
   :api_key => 'api_key'
}
```

Or better yet, add it to development.rb and production.rb files so that you can test it  better.

You can access this api_key from controller like

```
Rails.application.config.service[:api_key]
```

Comment: i get this error when i add it on dev and production and test. I integrated this with my url to look somehting like this. http://google.com + Rails.application.config.service[:api_key] (with inverted quotes for goole.com)undefined method `service' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007ffc842c2670>

Comment: You can create an empty hash in application.rb like 'config.service = {} and in your development/production.rb files add 'config.service[:api_key] = "api_key"' and still access it the same way from controller. And service is not a keyword and you could replace it with a suitable name of your choice.