# Ruby - Rails - encrypt stored passwords in rails' source code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I encrypt stored passwords in rails' source code? These are not passwords of the users, but passwords used by the app to access other external services; for SOAP, REST api etc. I can't one-way hash it because the app has to send a text pass to authenticate to other services. Base64 encoding/decoding isn't the best option since it can be copied from the source code and reversed.

Comment: Are you simply attempting to keep passwords & keys out of source control, or trying to obscure them entirely? If you just want to keep them out of source control, you should consider using environment variables. Check out this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7772526/689708

Comment: Thanks that is a good option. I would like to keep them out of the system entirely.