# Rails 4 + Paperclip + Devise + S3: Images not uploading to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have an `Active` model (you can think of an Active as a User) that has authentication setup with Devise. I am trying to add a `photograph` attribute to my `Active` model and be able to upload pictures with S3.

Migration:

```
class AddAttachmentPhotographToActives < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :actives do |t|
      t.attachment :photograph
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :actives, :photograph
  end
end
```

Active model:

```
...

has_attached_file :photograph,
  :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
  :storage => :s3,
  :default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png',
  :path => "users/:id/photograph/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => ... ,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => " ... ",
    :secret_access_key => " ... "
  }
```

Both `config/environments/production.rb` and `config/environments/development.rb` have the following:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV[' ... '],
      :access_key_id => ENV[' ... '],
      :secret_access_key => ENV[' ... ']
    }
  }
```

I have my form for uploading a picture in `views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb` like so: `<%= f.file_field :photograph %>`. However, after I select and update an Active with this form (the update goes through successfully), the path to my image (generated with `<%= image_tag @active.photograph.url %>`) is:

`http://localhost:3000/images/photographs/missing_original.png`

instead of an S3 address.

Also note I am using the following gems:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

I have never used S3 before, but after I select an image to upload and hit "enter" on my update page, my S3 bucket on the Amazon portal is still empty, so the update never went through.

Did I not set something up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine - are you sure you have S3 set up correctly?

Here is the code we use - hopefully this will help:

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image,
           :styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
           :default_url => "***********",
           :storage => :s3,
           :bucket => '*********',
           :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
end

#config/initializers/s3.rb
if Rails.env == "production"
  # set credentials from ENV hash
  S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "firststop"}
else
  # get credentials from YML file
  S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end

#config/s3.yml
development:
  access_key_id: **************
  secret_access_key: ***************
  bucket: *******
```

This works fine for us

Comment: Ahhhh okay, it was something in my `Active` model that was messed up -- `:photograph` wasn't an allowed attribute. Thanks! One more quick question though: what is common practice in terms of pushing S3 credentials to version control? What should I put in my .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

Don't leave those keys in your code. At the minimum, place creds in config/environment.rb file:

```
S3_KEY='myKey'
S3_SECRET='mySecret'
#etc.
```

Then reference them in your code as S3_KEY, etc.

More on this and related methods: [How do I store keys for API's in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295889/how-do-i-store-keys-for-apis-in-rails)